# Include records where admit time is greater than discharge time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a bridge table that is a combination of 2 dimensional records. It is working just fine but excluding 4 records where by the `admit_time` is greater than the `discharge_time`.

How do I modify my code to include the 4 records?

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(D.dim_patient_episode_key, 0) dim_patient_episode_key,
    ISNULL(S.dim_continuous_care_ep_key, 0) dim_continuous_care_ep_key
FROM 
    [TABLEOWNER].[dim_patient_episode] D
LEFT JOIN 
    [TABLEOWNER].[dim_continuous_care_episode] S 
        ON D.patid = S.patid
        AND D.program_x_tx_setting_code = S.program_x_tx_setting_code
        AND D.preadmit_admission_date + D.admit_time_of <= ISNULL(S.date_of_discharge, getdate()) + ISNULL(S.disc_time_of, '00:00:00')
        AND ISNULL(D.date_of_discharge, getdate()) + ISNULL(D.disc_time_of, '00:00:00') >= S.preadmit_admission_date + S.admit_time_of
WHERE 
    D.admit_time_of <> 'UNKNOWN' 
    AND S.disc_time_of <> 'UNKNOWN'
```

Comment: You should store your dates in `datetime` fields, not `varchar`. And then instead of `<> 'UNKNOWN'` you use `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: A few things: 1. your sample query doesn't reference a field called `discharge_time` so I guess you mean `disc_time_of` .. please update question.  2. You outer join to `s` but then you filter on it, making it an inner join.

Comment: As per prior commment I would be _really_ nervous about how fields like `disc_time_of` seem to be mixing datatypes. All date or datetime fields need to be stored in an appropriate data type (not a varchar)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you're looking for the current criteria OR when admit time is greater than discharge time.  Something like this

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(D.dim_patient_episode_key, 0) dim_patient_episode_key,
    ISNULL(S.dim_continuous_care_ep_key, 0) dim_continuous_care_ep_key
FROM 
    [TABLEOWNER].[dim_patient_episode] D
LEFT JOIN 
    [TABLEOWNER].[dim_continuous_care_episode] S 
        ON D.patid = S.patid
        AND D.program_x_tx_setting_code = S.program_x_tx_setting_code
        AND D.preadmit_admission_date + D.admit_time_of <= ISNULL(S.date_of_discharge, getdate()) + ISNULL(S.disc_time_of, '00:00:00')
        AND ISNULL(D.date_of_discharge, getdate()) + ISNULL(D.disc_time_of, '00:00:00') >= S.preadmit_admission_date + S.admit_time_of
WHERE 
    (D.admit_time_of <> 'UNKNOWN' 
     AND S.disc_time_of <> 'UNKNOWN')
     or (D.admit_time_of>S.disc_time_of);
```

Comment: I am looking for the current criteria in addition where admit time is greater than discharge time.

Comment: Can you be specific about any problem with the provided answer? Because it appears that it does what you ask